# Where can I find the EEPROM memory in STM32 Nucleo F401RE?

Tags: stm32, eeprom, stm32cubemx, nucleo

I'm looking for to store and read values on STM32 Nucleo F401RE and I need to find which sector and begin address to start with.

I did watch a tutorial how to do, but he's using another STM32 board.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RmRRPtxhCZE&t=500s

So I begun to download the data sheet
https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f401re.pdf

And now I found this in chapter 5. Can anyone tell me which is the EEPROM sector and the start memory?

[image: ee]

Comment: Somewhere in the Flash Memory segment that isn't occupied by your program, you can use that. Which address exactly depends on the size of your compiled file and where the next block starts. Typically you start at the end and move back n blocks (depending on how much data you want to store) and use that.

Comment: @RonBeyer In this case, I'm only going to store e.g 20 bytes. But I need to find the sector number and start address. I can't find a good start address and not a sector. Even if I'm probably looking at it right now.

Comment: It's at the bottom, called "Flash Memory", range either 0x0000-0x0007FFFF or 0x08000000-0x0807FFFF. The last memory range is the 7FFFF part, so subtract the block size from that and start your writes there. I think a sector is 16KB, so that's a good start...

Comment: Your STM32F401 *does not have any EEPROM*. It tells you on the 1st page of the datasheet that the only memories it has are up to 512k of Flash and up to 96k of RAM (depending on the exact variant). You can write code (or use an existing library) to be able to use some of the Flash memory sort-of like EEPROM - but then where it's located is up to you to decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 32F401 does not have any EEPROM.  It does however contain 512 bytes of user OTP(One time programmable) memory.

This organized as 16 blocks of 32 bytes starting at 0x1FFF 7800.
Than at 0x1FFF 7A00 there is a block of 16 LOCK bytes which control the OTP blocks(0-15).

You may continue writing within a block until you either have all zeros, OR the lock byte for that block has 0x00 written to it.

Locks bytes should only have either 0x00 or 0xFF written to them.  Other values may result in the lock byte being ignored.

In certain lock modes the OTP bytes may not be readable externally.